# How to make "git describe" mention the presence or absence of local changes?

Tags: git, version, revision

How can I check, in a script, if local changes are present? Perhaps in combination with `git describe`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to make sure that both the two following properties are met:

1. That there are no differences between HEAD and the index cache

   `git diff-index --cached HEAD`
2. That there are no differences between the index and the working tree:

   `git diff-files`

Both commands take a `--quiet` parameter which will set the exit code according to whether there are differences or not (starting some time after git 1.4). If you need to make it work on git 1.4, you need to run the commands without `--quiet` and check whether they produce any output.

**Note:** `git diff` is a porcelain command, and thus should not be used in scripts. Use above plumbing commands instead.

Example shell code, taken from my [git_version.sh script](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-radeonhd/tree/git_version.sh):

```
git_dirty=yes
# git-1.4 does not understand "git-diff-files --quiet"
# git-1.4 does not understand "git-diff-index --cached --quiet HEAD"
if [ "x$($GIT diff-files)" = "x" ] && [ "x$($GIT diff-index --cached HEAD)" = "x" ]; then
    git_dirty=no
fi
```

If you can require a git version >= 1.5, `if git diff-files --quiet && git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD; then` can replace above comparison.

**Note:** This solution (exactly like Antony's interactive `git diff HEAD --quiet`) only discovers *local changes* relative to HEAD. However, local commits can arguable also be considered *local changes*, and naturally will not show up in any diff against HEAD. You will need to check the SHA1 value `git describe` uses to detect whether HEAD is from a set of commits you consider not to be *local changes*.

Comment: See also my comments at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985301/how-to-make-git-describe-mention-the-presence-or-absence-of-local-changes/1985431#1985431

Answer (score 9):

Since git 1.6.6, `git-describe` has accepted a `--dirty` option. If you have uncommitted changes in your working tree then you'll get output like this:

```
$ git describe --dirty
1.0.2-2-g215081f-dirty
```

Comment: Beware: this only recognizes changes to files that Git is already tracking! If your local change is a new file, and you haven't staged it yet, you'll get an output like `1.0.2-2-g215081f` – indistinguishable from what you'd get with a clean tree.

Answer (score 1):

`git diff --quiet` returns with exit status 1 if there're changes and 0 if there're not.

Keep in mind that it will show diff between staged changes and the working dir.
If you're interested in changes between your HEAD and working dir, you should use `git diff HEAD --quiet`.

`--quiet` implies `--exit-code`.

Comment: I see two problems with this solution: a) `git diff` is porcelain, and git upstream strongly recommend against using porcelain in scripts. b) `git diff` will ignore any uncommitted changes already in the index cache.

See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985301/how-to-make-git-describe-mention-the-presence-or-absence-of-local-changes/1989142#1989142 for how to address these issues.

Comment: The question was about finding _local changes_. `git diff HEAD --quiet` finds _local changes_ being exactly the result of two plumbing commands you have advised. The difference between porcelain/plumbing is not so crucial here.

Comment: The git devs say to use plumbing commands for scripts, so I base my scripts on those. As to the *local changes*, `git diff HEAD --quiet` is certainly functionally equivalent to my two commands, but I would still prefer the API git upstream recommend for scripting cases.

Comment: I wouldn't treat git devs general advice to use plumbing in scripts so punctiliously. I can't imagine any use of git --quiet other than in a script, which indicates that _this_ very subcommand with _this_ option is an exception from the rule. And yes, parsing the results of git diff (without --quiet) in a script would surely be error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

`git status` exits with non-zero status if there is no local changes.

But I don't understand what you mean "in combination with git describe".

Comment: v1.1-5-g1234567 would mean no local changes and v1.1-5-g1234567(+) would mean with local changes. git status returned 1 here when unstaged local changes were present